# Косая или скрученная форма границы

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

Мне интересно, можно ли создать завернутую или, лучше сказать, скрученную границу с помощью `CSS`.

Эффект, который я хотел бы получить, смотрите ниже, в изображении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перевод вопроса: [Oblique or twisted border shape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27720098/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720098/oblique-or-twisted-border-shape

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Больше мне в голову ни чего не пришло но:**

```css
   p{
margin:30px;
transform:translate(100px,50px);
   }

p.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

p.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

p.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

p.arrow:after,
p:before {
  z-index: -100;
}

p.arrow:after {
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}

p.arrow:before {
  transform: skew(20deg);
}

p.trap {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #eee;
}

p.trap:after,
p.trap:before {
  z-index: -100;
}

p.trap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
}

p.trap:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
}

p.trap:after {
  transform: rotateX(-50deg);
}

p.trap:before {
  transform: rotateX(50deg);
}

   p.center-arrow{
display:block;
width:300px;
height:60px;
line-height:60px;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
perspective:100px;
color:#222;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:900;
}
p.center-arrow span.center-arrow-line{
display:block;
width:350px;
height:20px;
background:red;
border:none;
outline:none;
border-radius:45%;
border-style:solid;
border-width:4px;
border-color:blue;
position:absolute;
top:50%; left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
z-index:-1200;
}
p.center-arrow:after,
p.center-arrow:before{
content:"";
display:block;
width:100%;
height:30px;
position:absolute;
left:0;
z-index:-100;
}
p.center-arrow:after{
top:-10px;
background:red;
transform:rotateX(-40deg);
border-style:solid;
border-width:4px;
border-color:blue blue red blue;
}
p.center-arrow:before{
bottom:-10px;
background:red;
transform:rotateX(40deg);
border-style:solid;
border-width:4px;
border-color:red blue blue blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="arrow">Такой элемент</p>

<p class="trap">Трапеция</p>

<p class="center-arrow">
  с полосой в центре
  <span class="center-arrow-line"></span>
</p>
```

**Пример смотреть желательно в полноэкранном режиме**

Демо с background на codepen:  http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/EWpwVr?editors=1100

Answer (score 5):

### SVG решение:

Самым простым и аккуратным решением было бы использование `svg` для создания границы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
#content {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg width="200" height="30" viewBox="-1 -2 201 33">
    <path d="M0,0 h200 l-15,15 l15,15 h-200 l15,-15z" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Вы могли бы даже использовать `path` с квадратичными кривыми Безье для усложнения формы границы фигуры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#content {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg width="200" height="30" viewBox="-1 -1 201 33">
    <path d="M0,0 h200 q-20,15 0,30 h-200 q20,-15 0,-30" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <svg width="200" height="30" viewBox="-1 -1 201 33">
    <path d="M0,0 h200 q0,10 -15,15 q10,0 15,15 h-200 q0,-10 15,-15 q-10,0 -15,-15" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <svg width="200" height="30" viewBox="-1 -1 201 33">
    <path d="M0,0 h200 q-10,0 -15,12.5 l15,2.5 l-15,2.5 q0,10 15,13 h-200 q10,0 15,-12.5 l-15,-2.5 l15,-2.5 q0,-10 -15,-12.5" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Вы можете легко добавить эффект тени.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#content {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg width="205" height="35" viewBox="-1 -1 205 38">
    <filter id="f">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.5" />
    </filter>
    <path filter="url(#f)" d="M0,0 h200 l-15,15 l15,15 h-200 l15,-15z" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,3)" fill="black" />
    <path id="shape" d="M0,0 h200 l-15,15 l15,15 h-200 l15,-15z" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="white" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <svg width="205" height="35" viewBox="-1 -1 205 38">
    <path filter="url(#f)" d="M0,0 h200 q0,10 -15,15 q10,0 15,15 h-200 q0,-10 15,-15 q-10,0 -15,-15" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,3)" fill="black" />
    <path d="M0,0 h200 q0,10 -15,15 q10,0 15,15 h-200 q0,-10 15,-15 q-10,0 -15,-15" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="white" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <svg width="205" height="35" viewBox="-1 -1 205 38">
    <path filter="url(#f)" d="M0,0 h200 q-10,0 -15,12.5 l15,2.5 l-15,2.5 q0,10 15,13 h-200 q10,0 15,-12.5 l-15,-2.5 l15,-2.5 q0,-10 -15,-12.5" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,3)" fill="black" />
    <path d="M0,0 h200 q-10,0 -15,12.5 l15,2.5 l-15,2.5 q0,10 15,13 h-200 q10,0 15,-12.5 l-15,-2.5 l15,-2.5 q0,-10 -15,-12.5" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="white" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Перевод ответа: [Oblique or twisted border shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27720208/7394871)

Answer (score 4):

### CSS решение:

В качестве альтернативного решения вы всегда можете использовать - `:after` и `:before` псевдоэлементы.
Ширина и высота псевдоэлементов `:after` и `:before` - вычислялись с использованием некоторой базовой тригонометрии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прим. переводчика:
 У автора на рисунке ошибка - во второй и третьей формуле сверху.
 Должно быть: `opposite side = Sin(45) x Hypotenuse;`
 Но результат у автора, тем не менее получился  верный - 21.21px.

Противоположная сторона - ширина и высота псевдоэлементов `:after` и `:before`.
На левой стороне даны верхняя и правая границы, а справа - верхняя и левая границы.
Затем, левый край ленточки был повернут на `45deg`, а тот, что справа, был повернут на `-45deg`.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 27px;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div:after,
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 21.21px;
  height: 21.21px;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 1px;
  left: -9px;
}
div:after {
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>lorem ipsum</div>
```

Перевод ответа: [Oblique or twisted border shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27720208/7394871)

Answer (score 3):

Пример с использованием clip-path + FF

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b-ribbon {    
  position: relative;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 25px 10%;
  background-color: tomato;  
  text-align: center;
  color: tomato;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: segoe ui, sans-serif;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0%, 100% 0, 90% 50%, 100% 100%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0 100%, 10% 50%);
          clip-path: polygon(0 0%, 100% 0, 90% 50%, 100% 100%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0 100%, 10% 50%);   
     -webkit-clip-path: url("#clip-ribbon");
  clip-path: url("#clip-ribbon");   
  transition: .3s;
}
.b-ribbon:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 8px; bottom: 3px; right: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0%, 100% 0, 90.3% 50%, 100% 100%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0 100%, 9.7% 50%);
          clip-path: polygon(0 0%, 100% 0, 90.3% 50%, 100% 100%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0 100%, 9.7% 50%); 
     -webkit-clip-path: url("#clip-ribbon-inner");
  clip-path: url("#clip-ribbon-inner");      
}
.b-ribbon > span{
  position: relative;
}

.b-ribbon:hover{
  color: royalblue;
  background-color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-ribbon">
  <span>Text ribbon</span>
</div>
<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-ribbon" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">    
      <polygon points="0 0, 1 0, 0.9 0.5, 1 1, 0.7 1, 0.3 1, 0 1, 0.1 0.5" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>  
</svg>
<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-ribbon-inner" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">    
      <polygon points="0 0, 1 0, 0.903 0.5, 1 1, 0.7 1, 0.3 1, 0 1, 0.097 0.5" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>  
</svg>
```

Comment: Нормально работает в FF спасибо за вариант

Answer (score 0):

О-о-о-о-о-о... Я смотрю тут никто не знает о `clip-path`.
Всё легче, чем кажется. 
Но прошу ознакомиться с [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path).
Ну или если лень, то вот фотка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Также можешь наметить любые фигуры с помощью [этой тулсы](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/).

```css
div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orangered;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0%, 100% 0, 85% 50%, 100% 100%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0 100%, 15% 50%);
          clip-path: polygon(0 0%, 100% 0, 85% 50%, 100% 100%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0 100%, 15% 50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Какая чудесная погода...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: вариант с border - можете добавить?

Comment: @VostokSisters Нормально. Еще один вариант решения. Ловите плюс Справедливости ради, обращаю ваше внимание, что решений c clip-path в разделе по метке svg достаточно много

Comment: @soledar10 как всегда, жду ваш вариант :-)

Comment: @Alexandr_T, а как связаны clip-path и свг? Не понял

Comment: @Alexandr_T у svg есть свой `<clipPath>`, но причем тут css-свойство `clip-path`?

Comment: @VostokSisters ну ведь не всегда, только чистый svg в решениях, очень часто css+svg идет. Пробегитесь по моим постам или просто по разделу  с меткой svg.

Comment: @VostokSisters смотрел ваш вариант в Chrome всё нормально. Посмотрел в FF clip-path не работает - вместо ленты прямоугольник. Вспомнил, что для FF нужно в пикселях полигон задавать, проценты FF - игнорирует

Comment: @Alexandr_T, причем тут svg, если clip-path работает со всеми элементами? =_= Я этого не понимаю

Comment: @Alexandr_T, про ограничения в браузерах я тебе сказал. Поддержка 50% на 50%.